# How can I get the value of a row in a column in SQLite 3 table with Tkinter Listbox widget?

Tags: python, sqlite, for-loop, tkinter, listbox

I have Python program connected to SQLite 3 database with Tkinter on the frontend. My database table (subjectlist) consists of three columns: [id (unique interger), subject (text), serial (unique integer)]. Here is my program:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *


conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT COUNT() FROM subjectlist')
number = (c.fetchone()[0])

c.execute('SELECT * FROM subjectlist ORDER BY serial')
data = c.fetchall()
c.close
conn.close()


root = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
for i in range(number):
    listbox.insert(END, data[i][1])

def get_serial():
    print(listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

btn = Button(root, text="Show serial", command=lambda: get_serial())
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```

Currently at runtime when I click item on listbox (witch basically shows all subject column values) and then press Tkinter button I get the subject I clicked. Instead I want to get serial corresponding to the subject. Notice that subject column may have same value on two or more different rows. How would I go about achieving this?

Here is just one more example; If I have this table:

[image]

I want the GUI to show first all of the subjects in the listbox. Then I click "Cats" (on the the id row 3) and then I click the button, I want the program to print me serial 4.

Comment: Is this same table used with listbox too?

Comment: No. Listbox only shows Dogs, Cats, Cats, Birds all beneath each other. So id and serial will not be visible to end user.

Comment: Would appreciate taking a look at the answers, below :D

Comment: Sorry about taking time. There was nights sleep, full days job, evenings extra meeting and todlers hanging on my leg in the midle. I saw your answer like 12 hours ago, but couldn't comment it since I couln't test it then either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this should also be easy. But since there is a database in your code that I can't currently test this with it, I made some assumptions. Try this out:

```py
def get_letter():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    ids = listbox.curselection()[0]+1 # Getting the index number starting from 1
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM subjectlist WHERE `id`=?;',(ids,)) # Searching the database for items with selected items index
    rows = c.fetchall()
    print(rows[0]) # Print the first and hopefully the only item in the list
    conn.close() # Close the connection
```

This should print the rows which corresponds to the id, and since usually id is a unique number, it will only print out one row. I'm also assuming that you have both the database and the listbox in the same order or this might not work.

Comment: This gave me the whole row, not just serial. I can still extract that serial from that row just fine so no problem there. So I have to accept your answer. Thank you. 

However, once again I played myself writing the question. I forgot to mention that the table is arranged by serial and not by id. Then I could just replace id from select stament with serial and it would work, so no problem there either.

However still I could have serial missing from table if for example I delete Dogs row. Then I think this would break. 

You gave the right aswer to the question presented though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index of the item inside `listbox` to get the `serial` from `data`:

```py
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM subjectlist ORDER BY serial')
data = c.fetchall()
c.close()
conn.close()


root = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for rec in data:
    listbox.insert(END, rec[1])

def get_serial():
    selected = listbox.curselection()
    if selected:
        idx = selected[0]
        print(data[idx][2]) # print serial of selected item

btn = Button(root, text="Show serial", command=get_serial)
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```

Note that you should make sure `data` and `listbox` are synchronised.